# After deploying to Heroku my Ajax calls route to Heroku instead of the supplied URL

Tags: ajax, heroku

http://rocky-inlet-97225.herokuapp.com/jservice.io/api/categories?count=100

Instead of  http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=100

Any one have any idea why?

Comment: I've posted & updated the answer,

Answer (score 0):

You've supplied the URL without the protocol part (`http://` or `https://`), thus URL is considered a relative URL.

Prepending the protocol should fix the issue.

Update: prepending just `//` is often enough; it will mean that call will use the protocol client is currently on.

Update 2: sorry, I've looked at the sources of your site. Look at the line:

```
$.ajax({url: "http:jservice.io/api/categories?count=100"
```

- URL is incorrect. Should be:

```
$.ajax({url: "http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=100"
```